# Strange behaviour trying to detect errors selecting a database

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code in php:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","john","john");

mysql_select_db("data", $con);
if (!$mysql_select_db) {
    die ('Cannot use data : ' . mysql_error());
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test where huss='hussein'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "ADSDAD";
    echo "<br />";
}

if (!$con) {
    die('ERROR Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I was able to connect to the MySQL server, but I can't seem to select the relevant database.

Being printed is the hard-coded text `Cannot use data :`, but no MySQL error message follows it. If the MySQL connection had failed then I would have expected a MySQL error message to appear after the hard-coded text.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$mysql_select_db` doesn't really exist, does it?

Comment: FYI you never actually checked for _SQL_ errors.

Comment: you should read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style

Comment: Fixed your formatting and text for you. This is a one-off freebie; please do it yourself next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem's here:

```
mysql_select_db("data", $con);
if (!$mysql_select_db) {
    die ('Cannot use data : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

You don't have a variable `$mysql_select_db`, and it doesn't magically map to the result of the last time you called `mysql_select_db`.

So, instead:

```
$result = mysql_select_db("data", $con);
if (!$result) {
    die ('Cannot use data : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Or:

```
if (!mysql_select_db("data", $con)) {
    die ('Cannot use data : ' . mysql_error());
}
```